# Using jQuery to dynamically create checkboxes based on multiple attributes from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like for jQuery to dyanmically create a list of checkboxes based on the class/data present in divs. Essentially these checkboxes will filter through the products so that clicking a checkbox will show the products containing that tag in their div while avoiding any duplicate checkboxes.

**Sample:**

```
<div class="Shoes" data-size="Small" data-color="Black">
     <h3>Nike</h3>
</div>
<div class="Belts" data-size="Medium" data-color="Black">
     <h3>Belt</h3>
</div>
<div class="Shirt" data-size="Large" data-color="Blue">
     <h3>Polo</h3>
</div>
<div class="Socks" data-size="Small" data-color="White">
     <h3>Generic Socks</h3>
</div>
```

Expected output
Class Type

- Shoes
- Belts
- Shirt
- Socks

Size

- Small
- Medium
- Large

Color

- Black
- White
- Blue

Each checkbox needs to be able to hide/show the item.

[JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SvFCP/1/)

The code I have so far is from searching around/previous answers, however it is only creating 1 checkbox type which is for "class" and not creating multiple ones.

Comment: You suddenly changed your question after we took the time trying to help you :)

Comment: You were first asking to have a checkbox, now you want a dropdown with all the retrieved data, is that right?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally typed dropbox instead of checkbox.

Comment: Still...you have edited the question multiple times over the past half an hour. I was also trying to help you.....but not anymore..

Comment: @2pha I also lost my inspiration on this Q

Comment: Was just trying to clear any confusion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    function createCheckboxes($els, attr) {
        var props = {};
        $els.each(function () {
            props[$(this).attr(attr)] = true;
        });

        return $.map(props, function (val, key) {
            var $chk = $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox',
                value: key
            })
            return $('<label />', {
                text: key
            }).append($chk)
        })
    }

    $('span').append(createCheckboxes($('div'), 'class'))
    $('span').append(createCheckboxes($('div'), 'data-size'))
    $('span').append(createCheckboxes($('div'), 'data-color'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/guvHE/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/LzmTA/1/

HTML

```
<div class="Shoes" data-size="Small" data-color="Black">
     <h3>Nike</h3>

</div>
<div class="Belts" data-size="Medium" data-color="Black">
     <h3>Belt</h3>

</div>
<div class="Shirt" data-size="Large" data-color="Blue">
     <h3>Polo</h3>

</div>
<div class="Socks" data-size="Small" data-color="White">
     <h3>Generic Socks</h3>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var goods = {};
    var divs  = $('div');

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        var attributes = divs[i].attributes;
        var item = {};
        for(var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++){
            var attrName = attributes[j].name;
            if(!goods[attrName]){
                goods[attrName] = {};
            }
            goods[attrName][attributes[j].value] = 1;
        }
    }

    printAttributes(goods);

    console.log(goods);
});

function printAttributes(goods){
    for(var group in goods){
        var groupTitle = $('<h3>').text(group);
        $('span').append(groupTitle);
        for(var item in goods[group]){
            console.log(item);
            var sp  = $('<label>').text(item);
            var chk = $('<input>').attr('type', 'checkbox').attr('value', item).attr('attr', group);
            chk.bind('change', function(){
                filterGoods();
            });
            $('span').append(chk).append(sp);
        }
    }
}

function filterGoods(){
    var separator = '|';
    var chks   = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    var filter = [];

    //get filter
    for(var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
        var item = $(chks[i]).attr('attr') + separator + $(chks[i]).val();
        filter.push(item);
    }

    //do filter
    var hasAttr = false;
    var divs    = $('div');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        hasAttr = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < filter.length; j++){
            var filterParts = filter[j].split(separator);
            if($(divs[i]).attr(filterParts[0]) == filterParts[1]){
                hasAttr = true;
                continue;
            }
        }

        hasAttr ? $(divs[i]).show() : $(divs[i]).hide();        
    }

    console.log(filter);
}
```